# Schedule a Google Cloud Function with both custom header and OIDC token

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-functions, header, openid-connect, google-cloud-scheduler

I have deployed a Google **Cloud Function** which **requires authentication** to be executed.
Then, I've scheduled this function using Google Cloud Scheduler, and setting **authentication through OIDC token**, which basically is an authentication header in the HTTP POST scheduled.

Now, **I would like to provide some custom parameter to the Cloud Function as well, using the proper header in Cloud Scheduler**, but seems not to work.

I'm afraid that is caused by what stated [here](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.scheduler.v1#:%7E:text=Union%20field%20authorization_header,of%20the%20following%3A), that is, authentication headers are overwritten.

Anyone faced the same issue?
How could be solved?

Thanks

Comment: As a **solution I found to explicit the parameters in the body** (e.g. *{"n_round": "2"}*), and forcing in Cloud Scheduler *Content-Type=application/json*.

Then I read my parameters in the Cloud Function body using: 

    n_round = request.get_json(silent=True)['n_round']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Headers in Cloud Scheduler to add the headers that you want, except the Authorization header that is set automatically when you activate the OIDC auth.

You can also put some parameter in the body if you want, all depends where you would like to read the data (header or body.)

---

**EDIT 1**

I have a Cloud Run "logger" to simply logs the headers/body of requests. And it worked during my tests I have 2 custom headers + the authorization header automatically set. Have a look:

[image]

Comment: Yes, I finally solved by putting parameters in the body. 
Unfortunately, using Headers in Cloud Scheduler doesn't seem to work, at least when combined with OIDC auth.  

I tried to retrieve those parameters by using both: request.args and request.headers; both of them are None.   

I'm afraid that OIDC auth override them as well.

Comment: It worked on my side with the headers and the authorization. Of course, the authorization header is reserved, but the other header can be set as you wish.

Comment: You are right, I was wrong in the way I was retrieving header. The right way to retrieve headers in function body is: request.headers['param']. Thank you Guillaume